# access to bin counts in seaborn distplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, seaborn

In pyplot's [hist()](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=hist#matplotlib.pyplot.hist) function, we are able to access the values of the histogram bins (through the return `n`); is it possible to access this same information from [Seaborn's distplot](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.distplot.html)?  Seaborn only returns an axis object.

Ultimately, I'd like juxtapose a line plot on top of the histogram which sums the counts in the bins.

Comment: `ax.hist(yourdata)` ?

Comment: Or better yet use `numpy.histogram`

Comment: yeah i was looking at `numpy.histogram` is that what's being called in the backend by seaborn?

Comment: seaborn is just using the matplotlib histogram function, but I think that probably uses numpy behind the scenes (or anyway numpy will give the same answer).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For completeness, `numpy.histogram` is what I was looking for!

Comment: Could you elaborate on how exactly you got the number of bins from numpy.histogram?

Comment: @Plasma, just use np.histogram(data)? Gives you two vectors