# plot distributions (e.g. from bin counts) using seaborn distplot or similar seaborn functionality

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, seaborn

Seaborn is  imho a great package and [countplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html) is a great function with visually pleasing results.

There is a question on how to [access-to-bin-counts-in-seaborn-distplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31727280/access-to-bin-counts-in-seaborn-distplot). E.g. the current answer uses [numpy.histogram](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html).

The question is, after we get the distributions, and process them as needed, how to create a countplot-equivalent plot using the altered distributions, e.g.

tl;dr: Here is my problem (example taken from [seaborn.countplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html)):
[image]

code for copy pasting:

```
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="darkgrid")
titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")
ax = sns.countplot(x="class", data=titanic)

import numpy as np
titanic_classes = titanic['class'].map({s:i for i,s in enumerate(titanic['class'].dtype.categories)}).values
titanic_counts = np.bincount(titanic_classes)
#now add ship2 counts
ship2_counts = [8, 9, 25]
total_counts = titanic_counts + ship2_counts
total_counts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sns.barplot()`

```
sns.barplot(x = titanic["class"].dtype.categories, y = total_counts)
```

Comment: Thnx!  Actually, `unique` gives the wrong order (orders alphabetically), fixed the answer to use `titanic["class"].dtype.categories` instead.